# LUCENE.NET- how fix the query generatesd in C# (more of 4 clauses "OR" and multi field)

Tags: c#, lucene

build a query with more of 4 clauses in the search and multifield.

**QUERY GENERATE**

```
{(tittle:g?s* body:g?s* url:g?s*) (tittle:ge?* body:ge?* url:ge?*) (tittle:esg* body:esg* url:esg*) (tittle:esj* body:esj* url:esj*) (tittle:esy* body:esy* url:esy*)}
```

**CODE**

```
var a = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
        var MulField = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30, fields, a);
        BooleanQuery BooleanBuild = new BooleanQuery();                        
        foreach (string t in g.terms)
        {
            BooleanBuild.Add(MulField.Parse(t+"*"), Occur.SHOULD);
        }
        TopDocs topDocs = searcher.Search(BooleanBuild, cnf.limitd);
        /*REGEX
        var rq=new RegexQuery(new Term("tittle",@"(j|g|y)h?eh?sh?uh?s(\w)*"));
        TopDocs topDocs = searcher.Search(rq, cnf.limitd);
        */
        List<ObjJSON> docs = new List<ObjJSON>(cnf.limit);
```

**DATA OUTPUT**

[Click show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awDOB.png)

**BUT 4 CLAUSE MORE**

**QUERY**

```
{(tittle:gesus* body:gesus* url:gesus*) (tittle:gésus* body:gésus* url:gésus*) (tittle:gehsus* body:gehsus* url:gehsus*) (tittle:ghesus* body:ghesus* url:ghesus*) (tittle:géhsus* body:géhsus* url:géhsus*) (tittle:ghésus* body:ghésus* url:ghésus*) (tittle:gesus* body:gesus* url:gesus*) (tittle:gesús* body:gesús* url:gesús*) (tittle:gesuhs* body:gesuhs* url:gesuhs*) (tittle:geshus* body:geshus* url:geshus*) (tittle:gesúhs* body:gesúhs* url:gesúhs*) (tittle:geshús* body:geshús* url:geshús*) (tittle:gesus* body:gesus* url:gesus*) (tittle:gezuz* body:gezuz* url:gezuz*) (tittle:gesus* body:gesus* url:gesus*) (tittle:jesus* body:jesus* url:jesus*) (tittle:yesus* body:yesus* url:yesus*)}
```

**OUPUT DATA**

[Click show image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arjp2.png)

NOTE:only execute the 4 firts clausules in the query.

*tanks for help, sorry for my english.*

Comment: Sorry but to me it's absolutely unclear what you're asking for. Please check [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Si la preguntas en español yo te puedo ayudar en SO en Español

Comment: solved error add line in the code "BooleanQuery.MaxClauseCount=g.terms.Count;"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error is the number in `max number class` and type query, using`Multi Field Query` whit override `new string [] {}` accept RAW Queries in Lucene format